# Why my Model Form does not pass the validation

Tags: python, django, forms

I am writing simple blog in django and I gotstuck on uploading files.
I want to create template wher user can write post and add multiple files. So firstrly i have created models:

```
 class Post(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(verbose_name=u"post title", max_length=40, blank=False)
    body= models.TextField(verbose_name=u"post body", blank=False)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False)
    published= models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=u"data publikacji", blank=True, null=True)

class Add(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post)
    file=models.FileField(upload_to='adds', verbose_name=u"added files")
```

and after that i created template which looks like this:

```
    {% block content %}
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" adction="{% url 'create_post' %}">{% csrf_token %}
{{post_form|crispy}}
<input type="file" name="files" multiple/></br>
<input class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%" type="submit" value="Dodaj post"/>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

after that i wrote simple view which would handle files and post creation:

```
def create_post(request):
if request.method== 'GET':
    post_form=PostForm()
    add_form=AddForm()
    context={
        'post_form': post_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_post.html', context)
else:
    post_form=PostForm(request.POST)

    if post_form.is_valid():
        instance=post_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.published=datetime.datetime.now()
        instance.author=request.user
        instance.save()
        # import ipdb
        # ipdb.set_trace()
        for file in request.FILES.getlist("files"):
            add_instance=AddForm()
            add_instance.post=instance
            add_instance.file=file
            if add_instance.is_valid():
                add_instance.save()


        return redirect(reverse('AllPosts'))
```

but none of add_instance passes the validation "is_valid". But why?
And the second question is there any way to use Form in template against writing raw input for file? When i use AddForm i can only add one file what is logic.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that your form is always an `unbounded` form, which means that it is initialized without data. By data I mean `POST` or `GET` data from request or an instance of the model. `unbounded` form will always fail `is_valid()` and it doesn't make sense to manually assign anything to a form instance like `add_instance = AddForm()` then `add_instance.post = instance`.

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-view) explains how to use a form.

You cannot upload multiple files with one single form because each form is a `Add` model form. You should really use `ModelFormSet` for your `AddForm` to add multiple model instances in one submit.

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) explains how to use `ModelFormSet`.

By the way, I find the model name `Add` extremely confusing, consider changing it to `Attachment` or `PostFile` or something else.

**Edit:**

I didn't try it, but if you want one widget for multiple files, you can do this in views:

```
for upload_file in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
    form = AddForm(request.POST, {'file': upload_file})
    if form.is_valid():
        new_file = form.save(commit=False)
        new_file.post = instance
        new_file.save()
```

Comment: I save this files in object now and it works. Thanks for that. With formsets can i get effect that i have one input for files. I thought that formsets are usefull when u want for example put one form many times, but i want to see only one input there.